# Convert cURL to HTTP request (Swift 3) using Alamofire

Tags: xcode, curl, swift3

I am not able to get access token in paypal, Before that is this the exact way to do? I am a bit confused.
 This is what i really need to Convert:

> curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
>   -H "Accept:
>   application/json" \
>   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
>   -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp"
>   \
>   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

And this is the **snippet** i am using to convert it:

```
 let parameters = ["password" : K_CLIENT_SECRET, "username" : K_CLIENTID_SANDBOX, "grant_type" : "client_credentials"]

 let str = "\(K_CLIENTID_SANDBOX):\(K_CLIENT_SECRET)"
 let utf8str = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
 //let basic_auth_token = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
 let basic_auth_token = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let headers = ["Accept" : "application/json", "Authorization" :"Basic "+basic_auth_token!] 

 Alamofire.request("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers )
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
                        print(response.response as Any) // URL response
                        print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
                }
```

**Response** is here: 
I am getting three things as i printed: (but the response value is nil)

> Optional(https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token)
>
> Optional( { URL:
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token } { status code: 415,
>   headers {
>       Connection = close;
>       "Content-Length" = 0;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1";
>       Date = "Wed, 25 Jan 2017 06:00:37 GMT";
>       "Paypal-Debug-Id" = "6221061b57a0a, 6221061b57a0a";
>       Server = Apache;
>       "Set-Cookie" = "X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D88049752%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3Ddcg12.slc;
>   Expires=Wed, 25 Jan 2017 06:30:37 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/;
>   Secure; HttpOnly, X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01
>   GMT";
>       Vary = Authorization; } })
>
> nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, here it is:

> ```
> //GET ACCESS TOKEN
> let parameters = ["password" : K_CLIENT_SECRET, "username" : K_CLIENTID_SANDBOX, "grant_type":"client_credentials"]    
>
> let str = "\(K_CLIENTID_SANDBOX):\(K_CLIENT_SECRET)"
> let utf8str = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
> //let basic_auth_token = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue:
> 0))
> let basic_auth_token = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options:
> NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
>
> let headers = ["Accept" : "application/json", "Authorization" :"Basic "+basic_auth_token!]
>
> Alamofire.request("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
> method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding:URLEncoding.default,
> headers: headers)
>                     .responseJSON { response in
>                         SwiftLoader.hide()
>
>                         print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
>                         print(response.response as Any) // URL response
>                         print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
>
>
>
>                 }
> ```